django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_account.phone_number
As I tried to submit the Register Form, by filling in its requisite entries, the following error occurred. Kindly help me remove the above error.
IntegrityError at /accounts/register/
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_account.phone_number
Views.py of Accounts app

def register(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name= form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            username=email.split("@")[0]

            user = Account.objects.create_user(first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name, email = email, username = username, password = password)
            user.phone_number = phone_number
            user.save()

    
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)


models.py of Accounts app
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('user must have an email address ')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('user must have an email username ')
        
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email= self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superadmin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user



class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    phone_number= models.IntegerField()

    # REQUIRED_FIELDS

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.email
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    
    def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
        return True


Register.html
        <div class="card mx-auto" style="max-width:520px; margin-top:40px;">
          <article class="card-body">
            <header class="mb-4"><h4 class="card-title">Sign up</h4></header>
           
            <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
              {%csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col form-group">
                            <label>First name</label>
                              {{form.first_name}}
                        </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                        <div class="col form-group">
                            <label>Last name</label>
                              {{form.last_name}}
                        </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    </div> <!-- form-row end.// -->

    
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                             {{form.email}}
                        </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label>Phone Number</label>
                          {{form.phone_number}}
                        </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->
                    </div> <!-- form-row.// -->
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label>Create password</label>
                            {{form.password}}
                        </div> <!-- form-group end.// --> 
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label>Repeat password</label>
                            {{form.confirm_password}}
                        </div> <!-- form-group end.// -->  
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Register  </button>
                    </div> <!-- form-group// -->      
                        
                </form>


Share the RegistrationForm. Please don't store phone numbers as integers.

I have shared the forms.py file of Accounts app

You are probably not giving us the full picture. You probably changed phone_number field from nullable to non-nullable and haven't successfully applied migration to your database. OR whilst filling the form, you didn't enter a value for phone_number which is non-nullable from what we see in your models.py.
Django model fields are by default non-nullable meaning the database expects you to enter a value for each field. To make a field nullable, you can pass the arguments (blank=True, null=True) to phone_number field. It is possible that this was the case and you changed it to non-nullable without updating other existing Null records in the database phone_number column. You can also provide a default value to populate null records. phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=0123456789)
Then run:
python manage.py makemigrations

Followed by
python manage.py migrate 

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/models/fields/
